# Caesar Cipher encoding process (customizable input and shifting) in Python

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

So this code already works, but I would like to shorten it using list comprehension. Would it be better if it was in 1 line, or many? (I do know that readability is more important than short code, but I would like to master list comprehension, ternary operators, and conditional expressions).
Oh yes, if there is ANYTHING I can do to make my code better, more efficient, more readable and shorter, I would LOVE to know!

```
#Caesar Cipher, only lowercase and spaces    
listString = [x for x in input('What would you like to encode? ')]
change = int(input('How much would you like to shift? '))
change %= 26
def encode(listString,change):
  encoded = []
  for c in listString:
    if ord(c) + change > 122:
      encoded.append(chr(ord(c) + (change - 26)))
      continue
    encoded = [" " if x == chr(32 + change) else x for x in encoded]
    encoded.append(chr(ord(c) + change))
  return "".join(encoded)

print(encode(listString,change))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view more suggestions:

- Put the function definition at the top
- `[x for x in input()]` is the same as just `input()`. Strings are lists of characters!

Combining my suggestings with the ones by @I0b0 you get something like the following:

```
def encrypt(char, key):
    '''Encrypt lower and uppercase characters using the caesar cipher.'''
    if char.islower():
        return chr((ord(char) - ord('a') + key) % 26 + ord('a'))
    elif char.isupper():
        return chr((ord(char) - ord('A') + key) % 26 + ord('A'))
    return char

message = input('What would you like to encode? ')
key = int(input('How much would you like to shift? '))
print(''.join([encrypt(c, key) for c in message]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Pull out a function to shift a single character, and your top level code ends up being simply `print(''.join([cipher(character) for character in input(…)]))`
- With an array containing the alphabet and a shifted array (`"{}{}".format(alphabet[offset:], alphabet[:offset])`) you can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to avoid any `ord`, `chr`, punctuation handling etc.
- Use at least one linter like pycodestyle or flake8 to produce more idiomatic code.